# How to call a parent class method inside a child class method of the same name?

Tags: javascript, class

I'm trying to create a simple inheritance structure using the class syntax in ES6. I have a parent class with a method, say `update()`, and a child class which also needs an `update()` method. I would like a call to `child.update()` to contain a call to `parent.update()`, as well as containing some additional functionality specific to the child class.

I find that creating this method in the child class seems to overwrite the reference to that method in the parent class, meaning I can't call both.

Here is an example:

```js
class Xmover {
    constructor(x, speedX) {
        this.x = x;
        this.speedX = speedX;
    }

    update() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
    }
}

class XYmover extends Xmover {
    constructor(x, y, speedX, speedY) {
        super(x, speedX);
        this.y = y;
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }

    update() {
        this.y += this.speedY;
        // *** I would like this to also update the x position with a call
        //    to Xmover.update() so I don't have to repeat the code ***
    }
}

testXY = new XYmover(0, 0, 10, 10);
console.log(`Start pos: ${textXY.x}, ${testXY.y}`);
testXY.update();
console.log(`End pos: ${textXY.x}, ${testXY.y}`);
```

This produces the output:

```
Start pos: 0, 0
End pos: 0, 10
```

As you can see, the y position is correctly updated with the call to `XYmover.update()`, but this new definition overrides any calls to `Xmover.update()`. If both functions were being called, we'd expect to see an end position of `10, 10`.

I have seen people who don't use this class syntax get around this by creating a copy of the original super function in a way similar to this:

```js
var super_update = this.update;
update() {
    // ... other functionality
    super_update();
}
```

However, this doesn't feel ideal to me, and it also doesn't work with the class syntax (unless you define this `super_update` in the child class constructor, which seems like it would create other issues of having a full copy of the `parent.update()` function in each instance of the child object).

I am new to Javascript so I haven't fully gotten my head around the mechanics of using prototypes yet - perhaps the best solution involves these somehow? At my level of understanding, these would work similarly however, in that even if a prototype function was defined, creating a function with that name would mean that the prototype never gets called either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 super.update();
```

isn't that [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)? That will look up the `update` function in the superclass, and call it with the correct `this`.

Comment: ...I'm not sure how I missed this, but you're right. Thanks

Comment: @HG- it is one of those underused great new features of ES6, so it is no surprise that a lot of tutorials / docs do not mention it.

Comment: This is fair - although it seems to be almost the exact same syntax as in Java, which I used extensively in the past. I'm a little rusty it seems. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yup, `class` syntax was mainly added to make JavaScript more usable for developers coming from other languages, so it looks similar to Java by purpose.